# Modify server's variable from client's thread (threading, python)

Tags: python, multithreading

I implemented a simple network 'game' in Python - server draws a random number, and then the client tries to guess it. My application works great, when the client guesses the number, it disconnects from server (it is handled on client's side).

However, after the proper guess, the number is still the same. I would like to modify the application, such that when the client guesses the number, the server should then rand a new number, so other clients should guess the new one. How can I do this?

Some template, just to draw an attention to the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from random import randint
import socket, select
from time import gmtime, strftime
import threading
import sys

class Handler(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, connection, randomnumber):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.connection = connection
        self.randomnumber = randomnumber

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                data = self.connection.recv(1024)

                if data:

                    print data

                    try:
                        num = int(data)

                        if Server.guess(num) :
                            msg = "You won! This is the right number!"
                            self.connection.send(msg)
                            break
                        else :
                            msg = "Try again!"
                            self.connection.send(msg)


                    except ValueError, e:
                        msg = "%s" % e
                        self.connection.send(msg)
                else:
                    msg = "error"
                    self.connection.send(msg)

            except socket.error:
                self.connection.close()
                break
        self.connection.close()


class Server:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.address = (self.ip, self.port)
        self.server_socket = None
        self.randnum = randint(1, 100)


    @classmethod
    def guess(cls, no):
        if cls.randnum == no:
            cls.randnum = randint(1, 1000)
            result = True
        else:
            result = False
        return reslut

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.server_socket.bind((self.ip, self.port))
            self.server_socket.listen(10)

            print 'Num is %s' % self.randnum

            while True:
                connection, (ip, port) = self.server_socket.accept()

                c = Handler(connection, self.randnum)
                c.start()

        except socket.error, e:
            if self.server_socket:
                self.server_socket.close()
            sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Server('127.0.0.1', 1234)
    s.run()
```

Comment: Should each client get its own random number that it should guess, or there should be only one random number that all clients will guess?

Comment: @shanmuga: There should be only one random number that all clients needs to guess. The number should change when one client guesses it.

Answer (score 3):

Generate the random number that is shared between both server and all the client, there should be only instance of this, hence this should be class attribute.
Add a class function `guess` which return `False` upon incorrect guess and upon correct guess changes the `randnum` and returns `True`

```
class Server:
    randnum = randint(1, 1000)  # class attribute created

    @classmethod
    def guess(cls, no):        # To be used "guess" if `no` attribute if the same as `cls.randnum`
        if cls.randnum == no:
            cls.randnum = randint(1, 1000)
            result = True
        else:
            result = False
        return result

    def __init__(self, ip, port):
         # ...
```

The client should call this `Server.guess` function each time.

Comment: But when I try to print the number at server's side in `run` method, I'm getting the error: `NameError: global name 'randnum' is not defined`

Comment: @yak There was fixed a typo (bug).

Comment: Still, when I try, for instance, in server's `run` do ` c = ClientThread(connection, randnum)` it shows the error I posted earlier. Maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: You should access it using `self.randnum` as you have shown in the question.

Comment: Then I got another error,  near  `if cls.randnum == no:`, namely: `AttributeError: class Server has no attribute 'randnum'`

Comment: Look at the second line in my code `randnum = randint(1, 1000)` do you have this under `class Server:`

Comment: Sure, I have `self.randnum = randint(1, 1000)` but with your example, `randnum = randint(1, 1000)` it does not work as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143342/discussion-between-shanmuga-and-yak).

Answer (score 1):

Actually your issue comes from the fact that you create `randnum` as an instance method (see your `self.randnum`) as @shanmuga explained, if you simply declare it as being a class attribute, and remove the instance method it solves your issue (i.e. declaring it in the class directly).

As a side issue (not being an expert on socket), when you send message to the client, you might want to encode them as a byte object (in the `run` method of Handler, I changed `self.connection.send(msg)` to `self.connection.send(msg.encode())`). Also note that I used Python 3.6 (which mainly change the style of print statements)

See the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from random import randint
import socket, select
from time import gmtime, strftime
import threading
import sys

class Handler(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, connection, randomnumber):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.connection = connection
        self.randomnumber = randomnumber

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                data = self.connection.recv(1024)

                if data:

                    print(data)

                    try:
                        num = int(data)

                        if Server.guess(num) :
                            msg = "You won! This is the right number!"
                            self.connection.send(msg.encode())
                            break
                        else :
                            msg = "Try again!"
                            self.connection.send(msg.encode())


                    except ValueError as e:
                        msg = "%s" % e
                        self.connection.send(msg.encode())
                else:
                    msg = "error"
                    self.connection.send(msg.encode())

            except socket.error:
                self.connection.close()
                break
        self.connection.close()


class Server:
    randnum = randint(1,100)
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.address = (self.ip, self.port)
        self.server_socket = None


    @classmethod
    def guess(cls, no):
        if cls.randnum == no:
            cls.randnum = randint(1, 1000)
            print("New number is ", cls.randnum )
            result = True
        else:
            result = False
        return result

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.server_socket.bind((self.ip, self.port))
            self.server_socket.listen(10)

            print('Num is %s' % self.randnum)

            while True:
                connection, (ip, port) = self.server_socket.accept()

                c = Handler(connection, self.randnum)
                c.start()

        except socket.error as  e:
            if self.server_socket:
                self.server_socket.close()
            sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Server('127.0.0.1', 1234)
    s.run()
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot about the bounty. But I think my problem is more general than Python. How can be the same thing implemented in Java, C++, C etc.? The question is: I always have a problem when the clients needs to notify a server with a message, and server then should for example end working.

Comment: @yak Many problems can happen (lost of network, wrong handling of messages...etc)  I believe one of the issue in your design is separating class method and instance methods. For example, I would think that `randint` should belong to your Server instance as it is part of the state of this instance, and has to be modified once found by any client. Every time you need to modify the state of your Server instance (for instance closing it), it should be an instance method. You can make it work with a classmethod, but it would probably not be elegant.