# Stop server from client's thread / Modify server's variable from client's thread

Tags: multithreading, sockets, protocols

I would like to write an application that could stop the server based on client's input. The server is multi-threaded and I do not understand how can I do this.

Basically, I described my problem here: [Modify server's variable from client's thread (threading, python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757999/modify-servers-variable-from-clients-thread-threading-python).

However, this is the Python solution, not the general solution I could implement in Java, C, C++, etc.

I need to close other clients, when one of them guesses the number, but the server should be still alive, ready for the new game.

Can I ask for some advices, explanations?

I tried this (still do not know how to port it to C or Java), but it lets the clients send the numbers even if one of them just guesses it. It seems to me that `kill_em_all` does not do it's job, it does not close all the connections and does not disconnect the other clients as it should. How to improve this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from random import randint
import socket, select
from time import gmtime, strftime
import threading
import sys

class Handler(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, connection, randomnumber, server):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.connection = connection
        self.randomnumber = randomnumber
        self.server = server

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                data = self.connection.recv(1024)

                if data:

                    print(data)

                    try:
                        num = int(data)

                        if self.server.guess(num) :
                            print 'someone guessed!'
                            self.server.kill_em_all()
                            break
                        else :
                            msg = "Try again!"
                            self.connection.sendall(msg.encode())


                    except ValueError as e:
                        msg = "%s" % e
                        self.connection.sendall(msg.encode())
                else:
                    msg = "error"
                    self.connection.send(msg.encode())

            except socket.error:
                break
        self.connection.close()

    def send(self, msg):
        self.connection.sendall(msg)

    def close(self):
        self.connection.close()


class Server:
    randnum = randint(1,100)
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.address = (self.ip, self.port)
        self.server_socket = None

    def guess(self, no):
        if self.randnum == no:
            self.randnum = randint(1, 100)
            print("New number is ", self.randnum )
            result = True
        else:
            result = False
        return result

    def kill_em_all(self):
        for c in self.clients:
            c.send("BYE!")
            c.close()

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.server_socket.bind((self.ip, self.port))
            self.server_socket.listen(10)
            self.clients = []

            print('Num is %s' % self.randnum)

            while True:
                connection, (ip, port) = self.server_socket.accept()

                c = Handler(connection, self.randnum, self)
                c.start()
                self.clients.append(c)

        except socket.error as  e:
            if self.server_socket:
                self.server_socket.close()
            sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Server('127.0.0.1', 7777)
    s.run()
```

Client code:

```
import socket
import sys

port = 7777
s = None
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = socket.gethostname()
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))
except socket.error, (value, message):
    if s:
        s.close()
    print "Could not open socket: " + message
    sys.exit(1)
while True:
    data = raw_input('> ')
    s.sendall(data)
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data:
        if data == "BYE!":
            break
        else:
            print "Server sent: %s " % data
s.close()
```

Comment: Log in.  Using whatever protocol you have, send the server a message telliing it to shut down.  In the server, terminate your app when you get the shutdown message.  That's it.  It's not a problem with any OS I have used - any thread of a process can terminate that process.

Comment: In fact, I'll promote that to an actual answer.  I haven't answered anything for ages - it'll be a nice change.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit: But the server receives messages from clients in new threads. From `class Server` I do not have the access to the clients input. This is my main problem, perhaps I do not understand something here.

Comment: Oh - is the server just a subsystem of an app, not a whole app process in itself?  You need to shut down the server subsystem but keep the process alive?  That's indeed somewhat different.  If that is the case, you should add that important info to your question.

Comment: You can pass the `Server` instance to the handler , eg : `Handler(connection, self.randnum, self)`

Comment: @t.m.adam: I tried to follow your advice, but still have some problem. Could you help?

Comment: Sure, what's the problem ?

Comment: @t.m.adam: Thanks. The problem is with the second game. The first round is ok. When 3 clients connect to server, one of them guesses the number, then every client ends the connection (server still runs). When I run the clients (or client) again, even they guess the next rand number, it seems they do not receive the `BYE` message. Here's the output: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3269090dbdd6343223124ee3cce236d2. Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: In `kill_em_all` you forgot to remove `c` from `self.clients` but i don't think that's relevant. I recommend you remove the try - except blocks in `Handler.run` or print a very detailed error message, since you're debugging. Let me run your code, if i find a solution i 'll let you know.

Comment: It turns out the 'bug' in `kill_em_all` is more important than i thought. If you add this : `self.clients = []` at the end of the function, the program runs fine for multiple rounds.

Comment: @t.m.adam: :Thank you! Could please post your comment as an answer? I would like to choose it as a solution, because you helped me a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Log in. Using whatever protocol you have, send the server a message telliing it to shut down. In the server, terminate your app when you get the shutdown message. That's it. It's not a problem with any OS I have used - any thread of a process can terminate that process.